# Titan Security Keys - where can i actually buy one?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I keep reading I can buy the new Titan security keys as a Cloud Customer, but from where? Any ideas?

A

Comment: Like you, I went around the loop of Google links on this and I'm a Googler! I've filed a bug against the team asking them to add clarity on this issue. IIUC the keys are announced but not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

The official Google's announcement mentions that the ordering process of this product is being managed through the [Google Sales Representatives](https://cloud.google.com/contact/).

I think you should try to reach them in order to clarify your inquiries regarding Titan Security Keys.